# Retrieving single value from JSON.parse gives undefine

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I stored the value of JSON.stringify in storage and on retrieving it I parse it. Which gives me the following values:

```
{
    "name": "fagbemi Ayodele",
    "username": "fagbemiayo",
    "email": "fagbemiayo@yahoo.com",
    "createTime": "2022-08-05 03:28:41",
    "updateTime": null,
    "id": "130"
   
}
```

But when I tried to get name for instance, I get undefined in my console.

```
this.storage.getStorage('user').then((user) =>{
      this.profile = JSON.parse(user.value);
     console.log(this.profile);
    });

console.log(this.profile); //This list all the json data

console.log(this.profile.name); //Gives undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following, `line A` and `line B` will execute before `line C`

```
this.storage.getStorage('user').then((user) =>{
      this.profile = JSON.parse(user.value); // `line C` 
      console.log(this.profile);
    });

console.log(this.profile); // line A
console.log(this.profile.name); // line B
```

The reason is that promises evaluate after synchronous code.

## More

You might be wondering why this is working:

```
console.log(this.profile); // This has profile.name
console.log(this.profile.name); // Gives undefined
```

It's because chrome dev tools keep a handle to the object so if you mutate the object you get to see the updated result. This can get confusing. To see a snapshot of the object at a point in time, create a clone e.g.:

```
console.log({...this.profile}); // A copy of the object at a point in time
console.log(this.profile.name); // Gives undefined
```